# Como adicionar HTML com evento onClick no React

Tags: javascript, react

Pode parecer uma pergunta repetida, mas os exemplos que achei estão complicados e precisam de um array pré definido, eu não possuo isso, gostaria de saber qual a forma mais simples de adicionar um elemento ao DOM com React, já sabendo que não é como o jQuery e devo mudar o estado do componente.

**Update 1**: Estou adicionando código para explicar ao Marcelo melhor o meu problema.

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <InputMask maxlenght="10" className="form-control" mask="99/99/9999"  type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <InputMask style={{'fontSize': '13px'}} mask="9999/99-99999"   className="form-control" type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <InputMask maxlenght="10" className="form-control"  type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td >
    <InputMask className="form-control"  type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <InputMask className="form-control somatorio"  maskChar="0" mask="99:99" type="text"/>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Bem, eu gostaria de adicionar esse `tr` a um `tbody`, sempre que o usuário clicar em um `button`, mas ao adicionar, ele apaga o conteúdo já existente no `tbody`.

**Update 2**: Mudei a forma como é feito, usando state, segue o código

Componente

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    rows: []
  };
}

insereRow() {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    rows: [...prevState.rows, 'row1']
  }))
}
```

Renderizando no HTML, através do `map`

```
{this.state.rows.map((rows) =>
<tr key={rows}>
  <td>
    {rows}
    <InputMask maxlenght="10" className="form-control" mask="99/99/9999"  type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <InputMask style={{'fontSize': '13px'}} mask="9999/99-99999"   className="form-control" type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <InputMask maxlenght="10" className="form-control"  type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td >
    <InputMask className="form-control"  type="text"/>
  </td>
  <td>
    <InputMask className="form-control somatorio"  maskchar="0" mask="99:99" type="text"/>
  </td>
</tr>
)}
```

Botão que deveria adicionar um item no array, para que fosse renderizado outro `tr`

```
<button type="button" onClick={this.insereRow} className="btn btn-primary"><i className="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Atividades
                </button>
```

Entretanto da esse erro na linha do this.setState = this is undefined

Comment: Nada melhor do que a [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/hello-world.html), mas sua pergunta não esta clara, qual o problema que está enfrentando? Já tentou algo ? Coloque o código para que podermos te ajudar. Veja na 
[documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html) como renderizar o *HTML*.

Comment: Mas você só quer adicionar este `tr` ? Tem certeza que não vai querer adicionar outro. Se você só quer adicionar um, então eu já respondi sua pergunta

Comment: Eu gostaria de adicionar outros sim @MarceloRafael

Comment: Esses TRS, todos eles serão os mesmos ou irão mudar conforme o clique ?

Comment: Todos iguais, @MarceloRafael. Vou atualizar a pergunta com meus novos resultados. Fiz de uma forma diferente

Answer (score 1):

Aqui no meu caso eu criei um component `App` e um chamado `Hello`, o que eu fiz aqui é:

-Quando o usuário clicar em `<h1>Welcome...</h1>`, será renderizado com `ReactDOM.render` o componente `Hello`

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render()
  {
    return(
      <h1>Hello, I was inserted beibi :D</h1>
    );
  }
}
class App extends React.Component {
  insertHtml() {
    let target = document.querySelector(".target");

    ReactDOM.render(<Hello/>, target);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <h1 onClick={this.insertHtml.bind(this)}>
          Welcome, click over me
        </h1>

        <div className={"target"}></div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.querySelector(".root"));
```

```html
<div class="root"></div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Você poderia usar:

`target.innerHTML = renderToString(<Hello/>);`

Mas como você vai querer utilizar o `"<Hello/>"` para poder ser dinâmico, então aqui não é recomendado usar `renderToString`. `renderToString` é mais para [Sever Side Rendering](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Server-Side-Rendering)

Comment: Agradeço a resposta Marcelo, ja resolveu 75% do problema. Entretanto, tenho outro problema, que é o seguinte: Eu quero renderizar um tr, em um tbody através de um click, como você(muito bem) mostrou, mas o mesmo apaga outros trs que ja foram renderizados de outra forma. Como renderizar em uma tag html sem apagar o conteúdo dela? Obrigado desde já

Comment: Você poder criar um array de trs e colocar dentro do componente que dá tranquilo. Exemplo: A cada clique, voce criar um novo tr com `document.createElement('tr')`, coloca o valor nele e adiciona dentro de um array, no final só adicionar este array dentro do componente @ThiagoSouza

Comment: Marcelo, esse tr, é uma row com vários inputs e coisas do tipo. Como eu faria isso sendo que não quero criar um simples tr?

Comment: Existe várias maneiras, você pode criar um outro componente, ou pode fazer o que te falei que é criando um elemento com document.createElement() e adicionar filhos que também são document.createElement(), usando o createElement vai ficar um pouco dificil, eu preferiria criar um novo componente. Mas não sei exatamente o que você quer fazer. @ThiagoSouza

Comment: alterei a resposta para que você pudesse visualizar melhor

Answer (score 1):

Você deve usar [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state), ele deve conter dados específicos para o componente que podem mudar ao decorrer da utilização do mesmo.

> **State** deve ser um objeto JavaScript simples.

Para melhor entendimento, vamos criar um componente para trabalhar com contatos.

1. Crie uma propriedade no objeto `state`

   ```
   this.state = {
     contatos: []
   };
   ```
2. Crie um método para adicionar um novo objeto no estado `contatos` e outros métodos para atualizar esses objetos.

   ```
   // Método para adicionar novo objeto no estado "contatos"
   newContato = () => {
      let contatos = this.state.contatos;
      contatos.push({ nome: '', fone: '' });
      this.setState({ contatos: contatos });
   }

   // Método para atualizar o valor da propriedade "nome"
   // no objeto "N" do estado "contatos"
   // "i": índice, "e": event
   editNome = (i, e) =>  {
      let contatos = this.state.contatos;
      contatos[i].nome = e.target.value;
      this.setState({ contatos: contatos });
   }

   // Método para atualizar o valor da propriedade "fone"
   // no objeto "N" do estado "contatos"
   // "i": índice, "e": event
   editFone = (i, e) =>  {
      let contatos = this.state.contatos;
      contatos[i].fone = e.target.value;
      this.setState({ contatos: contatos });
   }
   ```
3. Template HTML

   ```
   {this.state.contatos.map((c, i) =>
   <div key={i}>
     <p>
       <label>#{i} - Nome</label>
       <input type="text" value={c.nome} onChange={e => this.editNome(i, e)} />
     </p>
     <p>
       <label>#{i} - Fone</label>
       <input type="text" value={c.fone} onChange={e => this.editFone(i, e)} />
     </p>
   </div>
   )}
   <button onClick={this.newContato}>Add Contato</button>
   ```

Note que, ao adicionar um novo objeto no estado `contatos` o *React* automaticamente renderiza esse novo objeto na tela sem a necessidade de chamar o método `ReactDOM.render` novamente.

#### Exemplo funcionando:

```js
class Contatos extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      contatos: []
    };
  }

  editNome = (i, e) => {
    let contatos = this.state.contatos;
    contatos[i].nome = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ contatos: contatos });
  }

  editFone = (i, e) => {
    let contatos = this.state.contatos;
    contatos[i].fone = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ contatos: contatos });
  }

  newContato = () => {
    let contatos = this.state.contatos;
    contatos.push({ nome: '', fone: '' });
    this.setState({ contatos: contatos });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="esquerda">
        {this.state.contatos.map((c, i) =>
          <div key={i}>
            <p>
              <label>#{i} - Nome</label>
              <input type="text" value={c.nome} onChange={e => this.editNome(i, e)} />
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>#{i} - Fone</label>
              <input type="text" value={c.fone} onChange={e => this.editFone(i, e)} />
            </p>
          </div>
        )}
          <button onClick={this.newContato}>Add Contato</button>
        </div>
        <pre className="direita">
          <code>{JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}</code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Contatos />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.esquerda,
.direita {
  float: left;
  width: 50vw;
}
.esquerda > div {
  padding: 1em;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
p, input {
  font-family: Lato;
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
label {
  display: block;
}

pre {
  background: #f3f3f3;
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

### Referências

- [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)
- [setState](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

Answer (score 0):

A resposta é simples, basta ler a [documentação](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html):

```
constructor(){
     //Você tem de dizer quem é "this"
     this.insereRow = this.insereRow.bind(this);
}
```